# how to get a similar plot like audacity with Scilab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, scilab, audacity

I have an audio file, that I analyse with audacity and the spectrum look like :

[image: audacity]

I would like to get the same with scilab so I've run this  code  :

```
[y,Fs] = wavread('fileName.wav');
Y_0 = abs(fft(y(1,:),-1));
plot(fftshift(Y_0));
```

and the result is :
[image: scilab result]

I tried this as well :

```
plot(10*log10(fftshift(Y_0)));
```

the result was different but still not the same as audacity, any  idea how to do it ? 
thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Audacity's spectrum is actually a [periodogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram), which is an estimate of spectral density. Try using the [pwelch function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html). Here is my Audacity frequency analysis:

[image: Audacity's image]

Recreated using MATLAB's pwelch function:

```
[y, fs] = wavread('inputfile.wav');
pwelch(y, hanning(512))
```

[image: MATLAB Version]

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need to understand both plots don't have the same magnitude ?